# Difference Between Class Operators

Tags: c++, class, pointers, operators

I am reading into C++ a little bit and was wondering if someone could explain some differences of some of the class operators to me. The operators in question are:

`* & . ->`

I understand some of them, however, I fail to see the difference between some. For example:

```
*x
&x
x.y
(*x).y
x -> y
```

Can someone use an example and explain a bit how they would differ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take this small structure as given for my samples:

```
struct MyStruct {
   int y;
};
```

---

`*x` dereferences the pointer `x`. The return value is a reference to the object pointed to by `x`:

```
MyStruct* x = ...;
MyStruct xval = *x;
// or
MyStruct& xref = *x;
// read up on references to understand the latter
```

---

`&x` takes the address of `x`. The result is therefore a pointer to `x`.

```
MyStruct x;
MyStruct* pointer_to_x = &x;
```

---

`x.y` accesses a member named `y` in the object `x`.

```
MyStruct x;
x.y = 5;
int a = x.y + 2;
// a==7
```

---

`(*x).y` is a combination of the first and the third: the pointer is dereferenced, and the `.`-operator is used to access a member of the object it points to.

```
a = (*pointer_to_x).y;
```

---

`x->y` is (unless overridden by evil people) a shortcut for `(*x).y`.

```
a = pointer_to_x->y;
```

Comment: To perhaps make *x and &x clearer: Since & gets the address of an object and * deferences an address, they can be considered "opposites". That is *&x == x is true. Or *&*&*&*&x == x is true likewise.

Comment: Thank you for the example and detailed response. Between your reply and the others I have come to a better understanding, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

`*x` is the dereference operator, if you have a `memoryAddress`, then `*memoryAddress` is the respective object.

The converse, `&x` is the reference operator, if you have an `object`, then `&object` provides the memory address.

For access variables, `x->y` is basically a shortcut of `(*x).y`, i.e. dereferencing and then accessing a member.

Comment: Thank you for further explaining the dereference operator. I was having trouble understanding this one in particular which was hindering my understanding from the last one

Answer (score 2):

Keep reading! I'll give a nutshell of a couple but it might still not make sense until you really understand some of the underlying concepts.

*x is a dereferencing operator. It means that it treats 'x' as an address to memory, and it looks up what is in that memory location and returns that value. So if x = 100, *x looks up what's in memory address 100, and returns the value in that memory location.

&x returns the address that the variable x is stored in. Imagine again if x = 100, but the value 100 is stored at address 50. &x would return 50, x would return 100, and *x returns the value stored in memory address 100.

The others require a bit more explanation, but also a bit more understanding of classes and structures. I suggest you continue reading and doing more examples, as will probably help more than a long-winded explanation now.

Comment: Thank you, I understand the basics of classes and structs, just didn't quite understand how some of these would be used. You mentioned doing examples, you wouldn't happen to know where I could use find some examples to test, would you? From all the explanations, I believe I understand it and would like to put it to the test!

Comment: Back in my day (not all that long ago actually), I got a book that came with a compiler and went through the book. It had lessons and stuff in it. Nowadays I think you can enter code online and parse them... it might be a good and easier way to try out code samples.

Answer (score 1):

`*x` is the `dereference` operator. That is, its the inverse of the `&` operator - it gets the value of the memory pointed to by the pointer.

`&` is an operator that returns the memory address of the variable.

`x.y` means to access member y of `x`

`x -> y` is a synonym for `(*x).y`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, your very first line is what helped me understand most of the others as I was aware of the `&` operator but not so much the dereference operator.

Answer (score 1):

- `&` gets the memory address of an object
- `*` gets the object pointed to by a memory address
- `.` accesses a member of an object
- `->` accesses a member from a pointer to an object

Comment: Thank you for the direct answer, it is appreciated. Glad to see that many, like yourself, are willing to help one understand these things.